# Finding the value of n in the given series

Tags: complex-numbers

The given series is $|i+2i^2+3i^3...ni^n|$.What is the value of n for which the given series equals $18\sqrt2$? Here $i=\sqrt-1$.

My thoughts: Actually I'm not getting any method to start off with this problem.Please help with hints, rest I shall try to solve.

Comment: Hint: Compute for $n=1,2,3,4$ and look for a pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  Note that $i^n$ is periodic with period $4$, so your sum is $i(1-3+5-7+\dots)+(-2+4-6+8+\dots)$  Sum the series and you are on your way.